# semantic_field_for for arbitrary attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, formtastic

I am quit new to rails. I have been using formtastic in my project and I find it quite easy to deal with the form objects. I have a small problem which I hope to clear out here.

I want to create a form for arbitrary objects and a has_many type of nested form for it. What I mean is semantic_form_for does not use any model instead uses symbol for creating form and this form now has to have a to_many type of semantic_fields_for. This is how my code looks,

```
= semantic_form_for :company do |f|
  = f.inputs "company" do
    = f.input :name
    = f.input :enterprise_code
  = f.semantic_fields_for :email do |e|
    = f.inputs "email" do
       = f.input :address
```

The form above is not associated to any model. I will pick these attributes in the controller and assign it individually. The email fields in the form has to be like has_many. Now, it is like one to one. How can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

I used formtastic only once so i might be wrong but i don't think there's anything mentioned that you can use it only for one type of association. It only says that you for nested forms we can use semantic_fields_for :model and then both model's must be setup correctly with accepts_nested_attributes_for